# Finding a file by alphabetical order

Tags: bash, files, scripting

Using bash, I need to be able to find a file in a specific position when listed alphabetically. For example, if I had the files `a, b, c, d, e` in a directory, and I wanted to find the third file, I would need it to return `c`. If I wanted the 5th file, it would return `e`.

Thanks for any help, sorry if this is phrased poorly, I'll rephrase it later if I can think of a way

Comment: should this work recursively, and if so, how does the counting play into that? do you only want *files* or would directories count?  what if there isn't a (say) 5th file?

Comment: If asked for a 5th file, there would be a 5th file. There also won't be any directories to worry about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `zsh`:

```
printf '%s\n' *([5])
```

Gives you the 5th non-hidden file in lexical order. Change to `*(D[5])` to include hidden files (note that `.` and `..` are never included).

In any Bourne-like shell, you can do the same with:

```
set -- *
printf '%s\n' "$5"
```

Answer (score -2):

This work in any shell: `ls | awk "NR==$fileIndex{ print; }"`

Explanation:

`ls` returns all the files in a directory in alphabetical order, and piping `ls` runs each file on its own newline, and `awk "NR==$fileIndex{ print; }"` will print the line number defined by `$fileIndex`.

Comment: 2 points: 1) [don't parse `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs); 2) the bash variable won't expand inside single quotes -- pass the variable with awk's `-v` option.

Comment: Hmm, didn't return anything for me

Comment: Make sure you replace $fileIndex with the actual index (i.e. 2) of the file you're trying to find.

Comment: I know, replace the single quotes with double quotes and it works fine

Comment: Fixed, thanks :P